# Finding a bijective function from $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ to $\bigl(\prod_{j\in J}X_j\bigr)\times\bigl(\prod_{k\in K}X_k\bigr)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> If $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets and $J,K$ are non-empty disjoint sets of $I$ such that $I=J\cup K$, then show that there is a bijective function from $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ to $\left(\prod_{j\in J}X_j\right)\times\left(\prod_{k\in K}X_k\right)$.

My function is
\begin{align}
f:\prod_{i\in I}X_i&\longrightarrow\left(\prod_{j\in J}X_j\right)\times\left(\prod_{k\in K}X_k\right)\\
\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)&\longmapsto\mathbf y=f(\mathbf x)=(\mathbf{x_J},\mathbf {x_K})
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{x_J}$ is a tuple such that $\mathbf {x_J}(t)=\mathbf x(j)\in X_j$ for every $j\in J$ and for $t\in\{1,2,\dots,|J|\}$ and $\mathbf{x_K}$ is a tuple such that $\mathbf {x_K}(t)=\mathbf x(k)\in X_K$ for every $k\in K$ and for $t\in\{1,2,\dots,|K|\}$.

If $\mathbf y_1=\mathbf y_2$ then $(\mathbf{x_{J_1}},\mathbf {x_{K_1}})=(\mathbf{x_{J_2}},\mathbf {x_{K_2}})$. This implies that $\mathbf {x_{J_1}}=\mathbf {x_{J_2}}$ and $\mathbf {x_{K_1}}=\mathbf {x_{K_2}}$. Then $\mathbf x_1(j)=\mathbf x_2(j)\,\forall j\in J $ and $\mathbf x_1(k)=\mathbf x_2(k)\,\forall k\in K $. Then $\mathbf x_1(i)=\mathbf x_2(i) \,\forall i\in I$. Therefore $\mathbf x_1=\mathbf x_2$, yielding that $f$ is $1$-$1$.

Am I correct so far? I think I am. However I doubt about how to prove it's onto. I have to show that $\text{Ran}f=\left(\prod_{j\in J}X_j\right)\times\left(\prod_{k\in K}X_k\right)$ but I'm having a bit of trouble writing it down. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’ve done so far is correct, except that $I$ is not necessarily $\Bbb Z^+$, so you can’t write $\mathbf{x}=\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots\rangle$; write $\langle x_i:i\in I\rangle$ instead.

To show that $f$ is onto, let $\mathbf{x_J}\in\prod_{j\in J}X_j$ and $\mathbf{x_K}\in\prod_{k\in K}X_k$ be arbitrary, and define $\mathbf{x}\in\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ by

$$x_i=\mathbf{x}(i)=\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x_J}(i),&\text{if }i\in J\\
\mathbf{x_K}(i),&\text{if }i\in K\;;
\end{cases}$$

it’s not hard to check that $f(\mathbf{x})=\langle\mathbf{x_J},\mathbf{x_K}\rangle$.

You can express this more simply in terms of function restrictions. Each $x\in\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is simply a function from $I$ to $\bigcup_{k\in I}X_i$ with the property that $x(i)\in X_i$ for each $i\in I$. Thus,

$$f(x)=\langle x\upharpoonright J,x\upharpoonright K\rangle\;.$$

Moreover, taking a function to be simply a set of ordered pairs,

$$f^{-1}(\langle x_J,x_K\rangle)=x_J\cup x_K\;.$$